# ejecting react native expo to react native bare problem

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle, expo

After I used `expo eject` I try to do `react-native run-android` and I get this error:

Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number. Make sure following dependencies of your project are resolving to one specific version:  expo-linear-gradient, expo-permissions, unimodules-core, unimodules-app-loader

Configure project :react-native-firebase react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Final Project 1.5 - Bare\node_modules\react-native\android

Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth :react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 24.1.0 :react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Final Project 1.5 - Bare\node_modules@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json :react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 6.7.1 (6,7,1 - 6007001) :react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 28 :react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 28 :react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 21 :react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\user\Desktop\Final Project 1.5 - Bare\node_modules\react-native\android

Configure project :react-native-firebase_storage :react-native-firebase_storage:firebase.bom using default value:
24.1.0 :react-native-firebase_storage package.json found at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Final Project 1.5 - Bare\node_modules@react-native-firebase\storage\package.json :react-native-firebase_storage:version set from package.json: 6.7.1 (6,7,1 - 6007001) :react-native-firebase_storage:android.compileSdk using custom value: 28 :react-native-firebase_storage:android.targetSdk using custom value: 28 :react-native-firebase_storage:android.minSdk using custom value: 21 :react-native-firebase_storage:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\user\Desktop\Final Project 1.5 - Bare\node_modules\react-native\android

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
individual deprecation warnings. See
https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Could not determine the

dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve project :@react-native-firebase_app.
Required by:
project :app > project :react-native-firebase_auth
project :app > project :react-native-firebase_storage
No matching configuration of project :@react-native-firebase_app was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr' with value 'Aar' but:
- None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

- Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
development environment set up:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed:
gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

The `android\build.gradle` file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {   
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        googlePlayServicesVersion   = "12.0.1"
        supportLibVersion           = "28.0.0"
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve these errors? I am stuck!!!

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?